# How to randomly a select a file with pickle?

Tags: python, pickle, turtle-graphics, python-3.8

For a school project I have to make a program that randomly selects a song from a file and inputs the artist's name and song title and the player has to fill in the blank from the artist name and song title in order to earn points.

One of the requirements for the project is that it randomly selects the file from the folder for the song so I've tried using the `pickle` module and `turtle` module - for the tab and somewhere to output the program if that makes sense and ive worded it correctly.

Unfortunately nothing seems to be many things. The biggest I'm having is because I've got the songs in the code it overlaps them in the tab when its been run and I want the program to only show one song at a time and hide the rest until the user has guessed

Here's my code:

```
import turtle
import os
import pickle
import random

#Screem
screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.bgcolor("black")
screen.title("Main Screen")

#Border
border = turtle.Turtle()
border.speed(0)
border.penup()
border.color("white")
border.setposition(-300, -300)
border.pensize(3)
border.pendown()
for side in range(4):
    border.fd(600)
    border.lt(90)
border.hideturtle()

song1 = turtle.Turtle()
song1.color("white")
song1.penup()
song1.speed(0)
song1.setposition(-200, -200)
song1string = ("_ost malone _n god")
song1.write(song1string, False, align="Left", font=("Arial", "14", "normal"))
song1string2 = ("_minem _ap _od")
song1.write(song1string2, False, align="Left", font=("Arial", "14", "normal"))
song1.hideturtle()

song1.clear()

songs = []
songs.append(song1string)
songs.append(song1string2)
pickle.dump(songs, open("songs.py", "wb"))

songs = pickle.load(open("songs.py", "rb"))

final_song = random.choice("songs.py")

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but have you tried to use the `random` module and then use the `random.choice()` method ?

Comment: yeah i have but it still over laps and if i .clear earlier on in the code it stays cleared the whole time.

Comment: Why is the title, and part of the body, completely different from the issue outlined at the end? Also, I strongly recommend using a context manager to handle file objects.

Comment: i dont know what you mean sorry

Answer (score 0):

Frankly I don't understand exactly what your code is doing, nor why you're even using `pickle`. Regardless, maybe the following changes with `# ALL CAP` comments indicating where they were amde will help:

```
import turtle
import os
import pickle
import random

#Screem
screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.bgcolor("black")
screen.title("Main Screen")

#Border
border = turtle.Turtle()
border.speed(0)
border.penup()
border.color("white")
border.setposition(-300, -300)
border.pensize(3)
border.pendown()
for side in range(4):
    border.fd(600)
    border.lt(90)
border.hideturtle()

song1 = turtle.Turtle()
song1.color("white")
song1.penup()
song1.speed(0)
song1.setposition(-200, -200)
song1string = ("_ost malone _n god")
song1.write(song1string, False, align="Left", font=("Arial", "14", "normal"))
song1.setposition(-200, -180)  # ADDED SO NEXT ONE IS ON DIFFERENT LINE
song1string2 = ("_minem _ap _od")
song1.write(song1string2, False, align="Left", font=("Arial", "14", "normal"))
song1.hideturtle()

#song1.clear()   # DISABLED

songs = []
songs.append(song1string)
songs.append(song1string2)
pickle.dump(songs, open("songs.pkl", "wb"))  # Changed file name.

songs = pickle.load(open("songs.pkl", "rb"))  # Changed file name.

final_song = random.choice(songs)  # CHANGED TO SELECT ONE FROM UNPICKLED LIST.
print('final_song: {!r}'.format(final_song))  # ADDED

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: im using pickle because i need to save and open it from an external file.                                                this is what i need to do for the project:                                         https://pastebin.com/jYPW1QXA

Comment: OK. The changes in my answer show how to `dump` the songs list out to a `pickle` file and `load` them back in from it (even though the latter isn't necessary there).

Comment: thank you so much. i have another question though: if i have multiple songs and it chooses one at random will it still show the other songs and over lap them in the turtle window? and does the print part at the end print into the terminal or actual turtle window?

Comment: i only want it to show one song at a time and then randomly select another from the file and put it in the turtle window rather than the terminal

Comment: The displaying of the `songs` list is completely independent of dumping them to a pickle file. To display them you will need to position and write each one separately while iterating through the list. You can randomly chose a song _from the list_ any time you need one. To select a song from the pickle file, you would need to load the list it contains into a variable beforehand — somewhat like the code in my answer does. Other than loading the data from the file first, `pickle` has nothing to do with selecting a song.

Comment: no i understand that the random module picks the song what i mean is i would like the random module to pick a song from the file and output it into the turtle window but only one song at a time with no songs overlapping you know?

Comment: as an alternative method could i put each individual song in its own file and then get random to select from a list of all the file paths?

Comment: `pickle` has one purpose, to save and restore Python data. Selecting items from that data is your responsibility as is displaying it. I don't think putting each song is separate file would help — in fact it would just complicate things unnecessarily and provide no benefits.

Comment: ok so bare in mind that im pretty noobie what method do you suggest? Also im sorry if i stress you out with my incompetence. But i truly do appreciate your help.

Comment: Sorry, this will be my last reply as SO isn't a consulting or tutorial website. Besides, the code in my answer shows how to do all these things you say you want to do. Python is well documentation and there are literally thousands of tutorials available online.